# How can I change the value of a masked array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, masked-array

In my code, at some point I try to modify a value of a masked array, yet python seems to ignore this. I'm thinking this has to do with the way memory is stored in arrays, as if I were modifying a copy of the value and not the value itself, but I'm not well versed enough in this to have any clue how to resolve it.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to do :

```
    x = np.zeros((2,5)) # create 2D array of zeroes
    x[0][1:3] = 5       # replace some values along 1st dimension with 5

    mask = (x[0] > 0)   # create a mask to only deal with the non negative values

    x[0][mask][1] = 10  # change one of the values that is non negative 

    print x[0][mask][1] # value isn't changed in the original array
```

the output of this is :

```
    5.0
```

when it should be 10.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, ideally this need to be scalable (meaning I don't necessarily know the shape of x, or where the values are non-negative, or which one I will need to modify).

I'm working with numpy 1.11.0, on python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04.2

Thanks !

Comment: Where possible using one set of indexing brackets, not several,  e.g. `x[0, 1:3]`; `x[0, mask]`.  But also keep in mind that indexing with a boolean mask produces a copy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's generalize your problem a bit:

```
In [164]: x=np.zeros((2,5))
In [165]: x[0, [1, 3]] = 5      # index with a list, not a slice
In [166]: x
Out[166]: 
array([[ 0.,  5.,  0.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

When the indexing occurs right before the `=`, it's part of a `__setitem__` and acts on the original array.  This is true whether the indexing uses slices, a list or a boolean mask.

But a selection with  the list or mask produces a copy.  Further indexed assignment affects only that copy, not the original.

```
In [167]: x[0, [1, 3]]
Out[167]: array([ 5.,  5.])
In [168]: x[0, [1, 3]][1] = 6
In [169]: x
Out[169]: 
array([[ 0.,  5.,  0.,  5.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

The best way around this is to modify the mask itself:

```
In [170]: x[0, np.array([1,3])[1]] = 6
In [171]: x
Out[171]: 
array([[ 0.,  5.,  0.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```

If the `mask` is boolean, you may need to convert it to indexing array

```
In [174]: mask = x[0]>0
In [175]: mask
Out[175]: array([False,  True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
In [176]: idx = np.where(mask)[0]
In [177]: idx
Out[177]: array([1, 3], dtype=int32)
In [178]: x[0, idx[1]]
Out[178]: 6.0
```

Or you can tweak the boolean values  directly

```
In [179]: mask[1]=False
In [180]: x[0,mask]
Out[180]: array([ 6.])
```

So in your big problem you need to be aware of when indexing produces a view and it is a copy.  And you need to be comfortable with index with lists, arrays and booleans, and understand how to switch between them.

Comment: This is perfect thank you ! This works and is scalable, I just have to rethink the way I approach masks and arrays. I wasn't aware that indexing multiple times caused python to create a copy, but this is what I suspected.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a masked array what you've created:

```
x = np.zeros((2,5))
x[0][1:3] = 5
mask = (x[0] > 0)
mask
Out[14]: array([False,  True,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

So, this is just a boolean array. To create a masked array you should use [numpy.ma](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.generic.html) module:

```
masked_x = np.ma.array(x[0], mask=~(x[0] > 0)) # let's mask first row as you did
masked_x
Out[15]: 
masked_array(data = [-- 5.0 5.0 -- --],
             mask = [ True False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 1e+20)
```

Now you can change your masked array, and accordingly the main array:

```
masked_x[1] = 10.    
masked_x
Out[36]: 
masked_array(data = [-- 10.0 5.0 -- --],
             mask = [ True False False  True  True],
       fill_value = 1e+20)    
x
Out[37]: 
array([[  0.,  10.,   5.,   0.,   0.],
       [  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.,   0.]])
```

And notice that in masked arrays invalid entries marked as `True`.

Comment: He can use this boolean array as a mask without using the `np.ma.array` step.  He's probably using the term 'masked array' loosely.

Comment: @hpaulj Probably. But I believe the best way to achieve what he want (to change values of initial array 'through mask') is to use actually a masked array. At least if I correctly understand the question.

Comment: Ideally I wanted this as simple as possible, meaning I have one array to work with and then through masks I modify this array without creating copies of the masked array (like the numpy.ma module does). @hpaulj 's answer did the trick, thanks.

Comment: @JesseRio You're welcome. But the good thing about masked array it's that **masked array didn't create a copy**: `masked_x.data.base is x; 
Out[12]: True`. It creates a view, whose memory is shared with x.

Answer (score 1):

To understand what's going on I suggest reading this http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/ViewsVsCopies.html

This boils down to the misleading use of fancy indexing.
The following statements are the same and as you can see it's directly setting to 10 the elements of x using mask.

```
x[0][mask] = 10
x[0,mask] = 10
x.__setitem__((0, mask), 10)
```

What you're doing on the other hand is the following

```
x[0][mask][1] = 10
x[0,mask][1] = 10
x[0,mask].__setitem__(1, 10)
x.__getitem__((0, mask)).__setitem__(1, 10)
```

Which is creating a copy with **__getitem__()**

In conclusion you need to rethink how to modify that single number with a different mask **__setitem()__**

Comment: Thanks ! This is exactly what I was suspecting, and the link you provided is very insightful. I've accepted @hpaulj 's answer since he provided a solution as well.