# Writable masked views into a record array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I'm not sure if I'm using the correct vocabulary here, but I have a use case for creating writable view into a numpy record array.  I'm seeing a discrepancy in the way numpy behaves depending on how I do the selection.  The following code snippet is a minimal example.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.asarray([(True, 1), (False, 2), (True, 3), (False, 4)], dtype=np.dtype([('b', 'b1'), ('i', 'i4')]))
mask = a['b']

a[mask]['i'] = 0
print((a[mask]['i'] == 0).all())  # this is false

a['i'][mask] = 0
print((a[mask]['i'] == 0).all())  # this is true
```

Is this intended behavior or is it a bug?  Is there some other way go generate a sub-record array that avoids copying the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so here is the deal. When you use your mask first, it is creating a copy of your array, therefore when you try and change the values in `a`. `a` is not being changed, because the change only affects the copy.

You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43921510/how-can-i-change-the-value-of-a-masked-array-in-numpy).

Comment: I see.  I guess I didn't realize the following two statements were different:
`b = a[mask]; b[:] = 1` and `a[mask]  = 1`.  Makes sense now.